# Direct update on state change (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, web-frontend

So I am currently facing a common issue in which the value of a state in my class component does not change immediately but only after rendering/refreshing the page. I have a state called 'auth' which I want to attribute the value false when clicking 'logout'. When a user presses the button 'logout' I want to immediately put the auth state to 'false' and then redirect them to the login page. But my issue is that this.state.auth remains true if no refresh/rerendering occurs. Keep in mind that it has to work in a Class component like shown below.

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../Context/AuthContext';
    
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    auth: true
  }

  handleLogOut = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
    this.setState({auth: false});  //Here it stays 'true' up until refresh ?
    this.props.history.push('/'); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={this.state.auth}>
        <div>
          <button onClick = {this.handleLogOut}>Log out</button>
        </div>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
};
    
export default withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous. You can't and shouldn't change this. The real underlying question is .. why do you need this change to be immediate? Are you running into an issue with the asynchronous nature? Explain _that_ issue instead of fighting react.

Comment: @JokesOnYou I'm guessing you want the `useEffect` hook, or the equivalent class lifecycle `componentDidUpdate`. Though it's unclear what you want. Shouldn't the `AuthContext` be wrapping the `HomePage` not the other way around?

Comment: @Evert, Yes I am running an issue with the asynchronous nature of the state change. I need to get it to be 'false' otherwise my loginscreen will reject a rendering as the context is supposed to be auth: false for that to happen. It feels so much more smoother when the value is immediately changed to allow other components to work accordingly with my Context value.

Comment: @JokesOnYou is this because of your redirect to `/`? You might want to use the callback argument on setState. This will be called *after* the value is changed.

Comment: @Urmzd, it is not relevant with the context wrapping in my case. Yes, you could say I want to use compondentDidUpdate. But does that mean I still will have to 'refresh' the page for that to work?

Comment: @Evert, Yes my redirect to '/' plays a big part here since it pushes the routing back to the login screen. In the login screen it would then check for the context value whether its false to actually render. I am not familiar with the callback argument ons setState. Could you send me some relating material or show me an example below?

Comment: @JokesOnYou I think it is relevant (though correct me if I'm wrong). Context is meant to data to its children. By pulling the `auth` state to the `AuthProvider`, you can use `useEffect` or the equivalent, to trigger the router to switch pages. By using `onComponentDidUpdate`, which runs after a state update, but before the component mounts (given the dependency array is not empty) you don't have to wait for a `refresh` (given that the router is correctly set up).

Comment: @JokesOnYou it's the other argument: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: @Urmzd Ah ok! So you're telling me that componentDidUpdate would actually do the trick (given setup is correct) for this issue? So in theory, I would be able to change the value of 'auth' in this function and get immediate update?

Comment: @JokesOnYou You wouldn't have access to the new "state" in handle logout, but yes you have access to the new state and the old state in `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Is this accurate code? Is this `Home` component still mounted after navigating to "/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, use `componentDidUpdate`.

You can use it as such

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  console.log(this.state) // Logs new state.
}
```

However, I recommend you move toward functional components as `componentDidUpdate` and similar class-based components are considered legacy.

[Resource](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: Yes, it definitely seems that Functional Components bring much more flexibility in storing data. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.setState(
  { auth: false },
  () => this.props.history.push("/")
);
```

Comment: OP, this is the most straightforward option (albeit less declarative than using `componentDidUpdate`).

Comment: Don't do this.... it doesn't really use the component lifecycle and doesn't translate to function component logic at all, and function components are the future of React.

Comment: @DrewReese If you're using class components, why bother with making them look like something they are not (i.e. function components)? Class components are no longer the preferred approach but they are still valid and supported, using the callback in `setState` is perfectly fine here.

Comment: @emeraldsanto Because if you don't understand the component lifecycle using the very explicitly 
designed and named class methods/functions because they are "too confusing" then you're going to have a struggle of a time in function components. The `setState` callback is an escape hatch, similar to `forceUpdate`. This *specific* instance isn't bad, but it sets a terrible precedence to possibly chain `setState` callbacks that enqueue further state updates, not something you want to be in the habit of doing when the component lifecycle is already misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little sandbox demo for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-forked-uznym

Your handleLogOut function will read auth as false until React rerenders the component. Barring any errors that may have occurred, you can log the state in the render method and see what it reads there.

```
  handleLogOut = () => {
    console.log(this.state.auth);
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ auth: false }); //Here it stays 'true' up until refresh ?
    // this.props.history.push("/");
    console.log(this.state.auth);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.auth);
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but it looks like it hasn't changed anything. 'True' is still logged after the state update